# sql server 2008 composite key

Tags: sql-server

How to set a field as a composite key in sql server 2008 and how to create a composite key in gui sql server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set "one field" as a composite key - by definition, "composite" means more than one.

In SQL Server Management Studio, you can highlight more than one column in the table designer, and choose "Set Primary Key" from the context menu:

[image]

That makes those selected columns a composite primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example in T-SQL. The first two columns comprise the composite key. In SSMS, just highlight the first columns you want to comprise the key and select the Primary Key button on the toolbar.

```
CREATE TABLE [Security].[MemberRole](
        [MemberID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [RoleID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [VersionNumber] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_MemberRole] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
        [MemberID] ASC,
        [RoleID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```